# android logcat empty on a real phone

Tags: android, logcat

I made example project, it's not big, but I think too big to post it here - so I uploaded it here
http://www.filedropper.com/logtest

Run from Eclipse on avd it works ok on device with Android version 4.2.2

My phone has Android version 4.0.4 and all I am getting is

```
    --------- beginning of /dev/log/system
    --------- beginning of /dev/log/main
```

What should I change/enable/set to get logs on my phone too. I want to let the app on a phone for "real life" testing and send logs back on my email.

(Any suggestions how to improve the code will be appreciated too)

Comment: Your problem is probably with whatever 3rd party mechanism you are hoping will collect logs and email them; this has never really been in the realm of officially supported functionality, and some methods which used to work no longer do.  For your own testing, you will likely have much better results using the official method via USB debugging with ADB (or using USB debugging to enable the official, but less reliable, ADB-over-wifi connection)

Answer (score 0):

That problem occur sometimes, you can close and run eclipse again it will work (This is in case if the debugging is working well with your phone).

Answer (score 0):

Strange thing happened and the same code is working now. It usually happens right after posting on stackoverflow :)

I installed aLogcat(free)-logcat app, I checked my logs, then they started working in my app too ?!? After uninstalling aLogcat, my app was still working.

My phone has no physical sd card - so this app maybe created image and mounted it somehow.

I'm not sure what exactly happened, maybe this post can help someone with the same problem. Thank you @Chris Stratton and @Bousselham

Comment: It's worth noting that the non-rooted logcat viewer apps don't seem to work anymore on Kit Kat devices. I believe this is a recent permission issue. I know this does not affect the version that you listed (ICS) but this has frustrated me on my Nexus 7.